# How to make a parent and child json tree in js

Tags: javascript

I have json like this:

```
data=[ { target: 'a', source: 'a' }
     , { target: 'a', source: 'b' }
     , { target: 'b', source: 'c' }
     , { target: 'c', source: 'd' }
     ];
```

but i want:

```
data= { "target": "a", "children": [
        { "target": "b", "children": [
          { "target": "c", "children": [
           { "target": "d" } ] } ] };
```

how do you write that in js

Comment: You have already "written it in JS", so what is your actual question?

Comment: JSON stands for "Java Script Object Notation"

Comment: you have to do a feedback

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, my internet was down for 2 days. I think I am not explaining clearly, I want write a java script to format the data to like a tree format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's the best possible code, but it works

```js
const
  data = [ { target: 'a', source: 'a' }
          , { target: 'a', source: 'b' }
          , { target: 'b', source: 'c' }
          , { target: 'c', source: 'd' }
          ];

let
  CurKey       = '',
  CurrentChild = null,
  result       = null;
    
data.forEach( elm => {

  if (elm.target === elm.source) 
  {
    CurKey = elm.target; 
    result = { "target": CurKey, "children": [] };
    CurrentChild = result.children;
  }
  else if (elm.target === CurKey)
  {
    CurKey = elm.source;

    if (data.findIndex(ef=>ef.target===elm.source) >0 )
    {
      let newElm = { "target": CurKey, "children": [] };
      CurrentChild.push(newElm)
      CurrentChild = newElm.children;
    }
    else
    {
      let newElm = { "target": CurKey };
      CurrentChild.push(newElm)
      CurrentChild = null;
      CurKey = null;
    }
  }

});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Second Case, without { target: 'a', source: 'a' } :

```js
const
  data =  [ { target: 'a', source: 'b' }
          , { target: 'b', source: 'c' }
          , { target: 'c', source: 'd' }
          ];

let
  CurKey       = '',
  CurrentChild = null,
  result       = null;
    
data.forEach( elm => {

  if (CurKey === '') 
  {
    CurKey = elm.target; 
    result = { "target": CurKey, "children": [] };
    CurrentChild = result.children;
  }
  if (elm.target === CurKey)
  {
    CurKey = elm.source;

    if (data.findIndex(ef=>ef.target===elm.source) >0 )
    {
      let newElm = { "target": CurKey, "children": [] };
      CurrentChild.push(newElm)
      CurrentChild = newElm.children;
    }
    else
    {
      let newElm = { "target": CurKey };
      CurrentChild.push(newElm)
      CurrentChild = null;
      CurKey = null;
    }
  }

});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: It seems like what I need, I am going try it. Thank you

Comment: Just one more question what happen when target: 'a', source: 'a' is not there. will this work? Cause I just realize there are no this kind of case in my data set

Comment: I made a solution for this second case, check it on my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr_1 = [];
var arr_2 = [];
var arr_3 = [];
var json = {};
var json_2 = {};
var json_3 = {};
var json_4 = {};

arr_3.push(json_4);
json_3.target = 'c';
json_3.children = arr_3;

arr_2.push(json_3);
json_2.target = 'b';
json_2.children = arr_2;

arr_1.push(json_2);
json.target = 'a';
json.children = arr_1;

console.log(json);
```

Dynamic adding to JSON `json_2['target'] = 'c';`

Comment: is there a way to make it dynamic, instead of hard code it in

Comment: @Lin Tong  Yes, If i you right understand. You do need example or you already got answer?